# when to compile SASS

Tags: css, web, sass

I am new to web development. I have read about SCSS/SASS and I realized it is not what the browser looks for, so it should be compiled to pure CSS. My question is did I get it right:

- whenever I make a change to my SCSS file, I should then compile it and then see the result.
- whenever I want to update my website, I should have a special script on my server side to translate the new SCSS files to pure CSS and that happens only once per update. (The number of CSS files is high and I wish to keep only the SCSS on my repository).

I would be thankful If you have any further information.

tnx a lot

Comment: You don't deploy SCSS code to your server it always has to be converted into CSS

Comment: You'll need a local build process if you're building a web application with Sass. Take a look at Webpack. Then, you'll develop locally and usually, the files are watched and instantly served to your local instance as CSS files. Then, after finishing developing, you create a final build with all the minified CSS files and upload that onto your web server.

Comment: You don't need a task runner to compile sass, it can actually operate from the cli https://sass-lang.com/install. But for development is for sure recomended to have some kind of task runner.

Comment: In short you will use an app to compile every time you save the SASS file. Gulp, Webpack, Prepos all are configured to compile when you save

Answer (score 1):

For compiling the **SCSS** to **CSS**, we use task runners such as **Gulp**, **Webpack** etc. I'll explain taking **Gulp** is an example.

**What is Gulp?**

> Gulp is task runner used as a streaming build system in front-end web development process. Mainly used the automation of time-consuming and repetitive tasks involved in web development like minification, concatenation, compilation, unit testing, linting, optimization, etc.

You can use **Gulp** for compiling your `SCSS`code `CSS` and through gulp, you can also keep watch over the changes live.

To install **Gulp** you must have [Node Js](http://nodejs.org) install in your system. After that use `npm i gulp-cli -g` to install gulp. You can find usage information on its official [website](https://gulpjs.com/).

To setup **SCSS** compilation to **CSS**, this is the best article you can find to getting started with Gulp for SCSS compilation and other tasks. [Gulp for Beginners](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

I will use [Laravel](https://laravel.com) as an example.

Laravel comes with [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix), which allows you to compile SCSS, LESS, etc into CSS by using Webpack internally. (it also does stuff with js)

Laravel comes with the folder [resources/assets/sass](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/resources/assets/sass) by default, and this is where you put your scss/sass files.

It then compiles those files and puts them in your [public/css](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/public/css) folder whenever you run `npm run dev`. You can also use `npm run watch` to compile those files whenever you make changes and save the scss files.

It also has `npm run prod` command, which compiles the files in a minified format, which makes the files lighter.

If you're writing all your css with SCSS you don't even need to put the public/css folder in your git repository.

Whenever you push changes to git and want to update them in the server, just update the server's repository and run the compiling command that you have.

If you're not using git to push changes to the server, you can just compile the CSS files using `npm run prod` and push these files to the server via FTP or whichever way you're doing it.